# How many eggs can I put into Isle Avue?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

The Isle Avue lets you put eggs into the hot springs to hatch them. I haven't been able to put in an egg yet since I don't have any. The other islands have different effectiveness based on number of beans. How many eggs can I put in the hot springs for each tier of beans on the island?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I think he's asking how many Pokémon eggs he can put into Isle Avue at each tier

Comment: Vemonus is correct about what I was trying to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [pokemongohub](http://pokemongohub.net/poke-pelago-guide/), it looks like this is the breakdown of Pokémon or eggs per level:

- at Tier 1, you can place 6 Pokémon or eggs.
- at Tier 2, you can place 12 Pokémon or eggs.
- at Tier 3, you can place 18 Pokémon or eggs.

Thus, regardless of whether you put in Pokémon or eggs, the cap is the same.